# WPF ClickMode Press and ShowDialog and TouchInput issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-10

I have a problem:

After touching button in current window another window opens by `ShowDialog()`.
This new dialog window has the only button. Click handler closes dialog window.

When I open dialog by touching button with `ClickMode = Release` (default mode), there is no problems.
But! When I try to do it by pressing button with `ClickMode = Press`, the first touch on dialog window is ignored.
It reproduces in win8 - win10 with touch (not mouse click, with mouse everything OK).

I suppose, there are some troubles with `Dispatcher.PushFrame` inside `ShowDialog()` and virtualizing mouse events in touch input.

**Does anyone have any ideas how to make button with `ClickMode=Press` work the same with touch and mouse input?**

My code

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleTouchCrash.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnPress" ClickMode="Press" Click="BtnPress_OnClick" Height="100">Mode: Press</Button>
         <Button x:Name="btnRelease" Click="BtnPress_OnClick" Height="100">Mode: Release</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
using System.Windows;       
namespace SimpleTouchCrash
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void BtnPress_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dlg= new Dialog();
            dlg.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

`Dialog.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleTouchCrash.Dialog"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="Dialog" Height="300" Width="300">
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="btnCloseDialog" Click="BtnCloseDialog_OnClick">Close me!</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

`Dialog.xaml.cs`

```
using System.Windows;
    namespace SimpleTouchCrash
    {
        public partial class Dialog 
        {
            public Dialog()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void BtnCloseDialog_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Close();
            }
        };
    }
```

P.S. I know there is a "hack" to disable touch input:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1016534
But using this "hack" in Windows 10 [November release 1511] every touch causes exception.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: ???????? ?? ????? ???? ??????????????.
??? ?????????: key
   ? System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   ? System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   ? System.Windows.Input.StylusLogic.ProcessInputReport(RawStylusInputReport inputReport)
   ? System.Windows.Input.PenContext.FirePenInRange(Int32 stylusPointerId, Int32[] data, Int32 timestamp)
   ? System.Windows.Input.PenThreadWorker.FireEvent(PenContext penContext, Int32 evt, Int32 stylusPointerId, Int32 cPackets, Int32 cbPacket, IntPtr pPackets)
   ? System.Windows.Input.PenThreadWorker.ThreadProc()
   ? System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   ? System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   ? System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   ? System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   ? System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

P.P.S. I know about MS Surface SDK https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716
But I can't use it because my app should run on Windows XP also.